# How to handle special characters .htaccess rules?

Tags: .htaccess

In my .htaccess file I have the following rewrite rule. I know limão.com is xn--limo-ioa.com in the url.
If I enter limão.com I can not open the page, xn--limo-ioa.com is workin fine. How do I write the correct rewrite rule?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^limão.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.limão.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The host name used in the request that was send to your server, will always be the `xn--` version, so that is what you have to check for in your condition. A host name does not contain slashes though.

Comment: Can you give an example how that will look like? I found multiple subjects on Stack overflow about special characters in .htaccess, but I could not figure out how to implement this in my .htaccess.

Comment: `^xn--limo-ioa\.com$`

Comment: Solved and all working perfect. Thank you!